# need to create 4 group using the data

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, pca

i have to create four group using this data :-

```
Own_House   Own_vehicle Monthly_Salary  Standard_Savings Bank_Debts Person_ID                   
1   0   1   66278   3989    1
2   0   0   64701   7076    1
3   1   1   28045   5659    1
4   0   0   21690   6314    0
5   0   0   67479   9894    0
... ... ... ... ... ...
1996    0   1   54292   1468    1
1997    1   0   63079   7574    0
1998    1   0   69959   1788    1
1999    0   1   70333   7494    0
2000    0   0   83376   8616    0
```

i have used ***KMeans PCA*** but not getting so accurate results.

please assist me how to solve this dataset to get the better groups/ clusters.

Comment: K-Means or PCA are standard clustering techniques, I'd say that they are appropriate choices. How do you measure whether the result is accurate or not? It seems that you are expecting a particular outcome from the clustering process, this often leads to disappointment ;)

Comment: You really got a point that for expecting the particular outcome will leads to disappointment, actually i am comparing the output with another model with is already there... and on the basis of that i am saying that my result is not that accurate.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that the previous model is really good in the first place? If not there's not way to tell if your new model is better or not.